# Vb6 “Tag” property equivalent in ASP.Net, BUT...available at design time within the aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, controls, webforms, tag-property

I have an extension to this question:
[Vb6 "Tag" property equivalent in ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183093/vb6-tag-property-equivalent-in-asp-net)

The solution to that is excellent, but I want to be able to set the Tag property at design time within the aspx file, ie:

```
<asp:TextBox id="myTextBox" Tag="thisIsMyTag" .....
```

Note:  I do not want to inherit and extend each control I want to have this property available on.

Possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. Sorry. Extension controls don't (or at least, didn't used to) work in the WebForms designer.